# parenting do not cause translate offset - strange behaviour

Tags: maya, mel, pymel

I'm setting the object as a child of another object.

Usually it's [0,0,0] translation point is then set to the pivot of the parent object and the child gains some offset in location to maintain position.
I do not know it does not work like that in my scene. The child bject maintains position, but the translation is still set to [0,0,0] and the pivot do not move to the parent's pivot position.

Why? Why does the object display some strange location and not world? Why no offset is applied and the position do not change to parent?

Regards

Comment: Are you doing this interactiely or with a script? The reparenting behavior is controlled by the flags on the `parent` command: see http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/parent.html

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it by script, but when I did it by hand the same thing happened. By the waf: location of parent was displayed as 0, 0, 0(pivot was not placed at the orgin, I do not know why) but when I've read rotatePivot it has proper position. I'll check the options|| Anyway, I've used LinkConstraint, so this is not that urgent matter now, but I'd like to find the root cause

Comment: If you just call `parent()` without flags, you'll get the behavior specified in the option box for the user action -- which means the same code can do different things depending on things a user has done in the UI.